# How do I link my old clash of clans village to my new account

Tags: clash-of-clans

My clash of clans account is linked to my dads Game Center acount and I want to link it to my account. How?

Answer (score 2):

If you still have a phone or device on which you can access the old account you can sign in to your new game centre account on this device and link the village to your new account. This can be done in the settings of Clash of Clans. If you do not have this device anymore you can log in to your dad's game centre on your new device, and import your village to the new phone (Clash of Clans will ask you if you want to do this after linking your dads account in the settings). After this you can remove your dad's game centre account and you will be done.

Source: My own experience with Clash of Clans